# Semicolon after "id" is a unexpected token

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a model in an express.js program but when I try to run the main server, I get the following error.

```
   id;
     ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
    at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
```

The score.js code is the following

```
class Score {
   id;
   title;
   userId;
   pageCount;
   baseUrl;
   vector = false;

   pageUrls() {
      let urls = [];
      let extension = this.vector ? "svg" : "png";
      for (let i = 0; i < this.pageCount; i++) {
         urls.push(`${this.baseUrl}score_${i}.${extension}`);
      }
      return urls;
   }
}

module.exports = Score;
```

How do I fix this error and what is happening to make this happen?

Comment: What version of node.js are you using? Field declarations were added in 12.0.

Comment: I am using node version 10.15.3. Is that too old?

Comment: At this point? [probably](https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/): the current active LTS is v12, and the current version is v14 (which will become LTS in November, so you have some time yet, but it might make sense to just skip over 12 entirely)

Comment: How do i update node. I am using glitch.me to host my project and I don't know what the maximum version of supported node. Even after some google searches.

Answer (score 0):

Use a constructor to define values.

```
class Score {
    constructor(id, title, userId, pageCount, baseUrl) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.pageCount = pageCount;
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
        this.vector = false;
    }

   pageUrls() {
      let urls = [];
      let extension = this.vector ? "svg" : "png";
      for (let i = 0; i < this.pageCount; i++) {
         urls.push(`${this.baseUrl}score_${i}.${extension}`);
      }
      return urls;
   }
}

module.exports = Score;
```

Comment: To update your node version, it depends on your operating system. Look on this site : https://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/update-node-js-latest-version/